# Save Google maps as ecw or tiff

Tags: qgis, google-maps, ecw

I've downloaded this Google Maps XML:

http://ttmaps.free.fr/files/google_maps_20.xml

I can load it in QGIS, for example, and view it as a raster.

I want to save an small area (a town) in an ecw or a tiff in order to create an WMS later, and be able to add the layer in another (not so modern) GIS than can't load xml.

I've followed the steps posted here:

http://ttmaps.free.fr/forums/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=459

It seems that it can be done in QGIS but the ECW SDK version 3.3 is needed, which i can't find it anywhere. So, my QGIS won't save ECWs and if i try to save it as TIFF i can only save it with a 20% of output size which is no good if i try to make zoom on an area later on. If a try it with more than 20% i get the following error:

ERROR 2: C:\Users\agmartin\Desktop\google_maps_20.xml, band 1: Out of memory in InitBlockInfo(). ERROR 2: C:\Users\agmartin\Desktop\google_maps_20.xml, band 1: Out of memory in InitBlockInfo().

I am using a new computer so i guess its not a hardware problem. SO: Windows 7 64bits. Processor: Intel Xeon E3-1240 V2 RAM: 20GB

Is there any other software or procedure to save a google maps area on ecw or tiff with good quality (zoom levels)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ERROR 2: C:\Users\agmartin\Desktop\google_maps_20.xml, band 1: Out of memory in InitBlockInfo().
ERROR 2: C:\Users\agmartin\Desktop\google_maps_20.xml, band 1: Out of memory in InitBlockInfo().
```

it sounds to me like a windows problem. Some time ago I did a png to geotiff conversion with GDAL (installed in linux), but the data were stored on windows (I have double partition). This didn't work because I got an error message. After googleing around I found that this happens when the process runs in windows. In my case, the process run in linux, but the data were in windows. So I moved the data to linux, run the process again and everything went like a charm. If you have linux, try putting this xml there and run the process again (you need to have the related software in linux).

However, this is only a guess but probably this xml is pushing data directly from google maps or something like that, not sure if that is "legal" in google terms, perhaps that's causing the connection/downloading problem (if it were the case).

For WMS using google, check this:

[peterdamen.com/GoogleWMS](http://peterdamen.com/GoogleWMS)

it may help you even though it's not been updated for a while, the same here:

[sourceforge.net/projects/googlewms](http://sourceforge.net/projects/googlewms)

Comment: i don't have any machine with linux to test what you say...I've tested it on windows XP too, but without success...

Comment: If this would violate the Google Maps ToS, is there any other map (bing, yahoo, Openstreet..) that i could use in a GIS via WMS or something like that?

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Your tilelevel 20 is very high. Set it to 18, your resulting files will be 4x smaller, so you will probably not run out of memory. Zoomlevel 20 is beyond what you see in a normal google maps web viewer (which zooms up to 19). All detail is visible at 18.

All of this apart from the fact that this is not allowed by google.